# readLines and writeLines R

Tags: xml, r, encoding

I have two ANSI xml files and inserted them in R. I used readLines to read them, did some modifications and used writeLines to extract them. But the output came out as one file - ANSI and another file - ANSI as UTF-8. I need both the files in ANSI as UTF-8 or UTF-8.

The code is too long and this is what I can share. I have used functions like gsub, grepl etc

Code:

```
x <- "123.xml"
x1 <- readLines(x)
writeLines(x1,"123_1.xml")
```

Comment: Try using  `useBytes = TRUE` in  `writeLines`

Comment: @user227710 It did not work. It converted to only ANSI. I want to convert it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following text at the beginning of the xml and it changed to UTF-8.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```